# Проблема в VS2017 с add-migration : The term 'add-migration' is not recognized

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Добрый день!

Пожалуйста, подскажите как решить проблему в VS 2017 с 
add-migration : The term 'add-migration' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Установлены последние обновления для VS 2017. Рестарт VS не помогает решить ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: EF установлено?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обязательно должен быть установлен компонент NuGet 
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.